# complex root homogeneous ODE solution: $A\cos(\omega t+p)$ or $A\cos(\omega t) + B\sin(\omega t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

Let's say I have the DE:

$$LCv^{''} + v = 0$$

I find the characteristic equation:

$$LCr^2 + 1 = 0$$

This give me the complex roots:

$$r = \pm i\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$$

where the components of the complex number are:

$$r = \alpha \pm i \beta$$

and:

$$\alpha = 0$$

$$\beta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$$

Now my question is this, my DE textbook say the solution to the homogeneous DE with complex characteristic roots is this:

$$v(t) = A e^{\alpha t} \cos(\beta t) + B e^{\alpha t} \sin(\beta t)\tag{1}$$

however, my circuit analysis textbook say the solution is this:

$$v(t) = C e^{\alpha t} \cos(\beta t + \phi)\tag{2}$$

without any explanation on why its different from the differential equations text book.  Why is the equation (2) solution the same as the same as equation (1) solution?

**Is there a way to prove that (1) is equivalent to (2) using trig identities?**

Comment: Both solution are equivalent. Use $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b).....$ formula

Answer (score 3):

Both solution are equivalent. Use the following formula:
$$\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$$
Then:
$$\cos(\beta t+\phi)=\cos(\beta t)\cos(\phi)-\sin(\beta t)\sin(\phi)$$
And note that $\cos(\phi)$ and $\sin(\phi)$ are just constants.
$$Ce^{\alpha t}\cos(\beta t+\phi)=e^{\alpha t}(C\cos(\phi)\cos(\beta t)-C\sin(\phi)\sin(\beta t))$$
$$Ce^{\alpha t}\cos(\beta t+\phi)=e^{\alpha t}(A\cos(\beta t)+B\sin(\beta t))$$
With $A=C\cos(\phi)$ and $B=-C\sin(\phi)$